# Why does `WHERE column` give a different result than `WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND column <> ''`?

Tags: mysql

I have two columns, area and block, where area is an int type and block is a varchar.

Now I am writing two queries:

```
select * from table where area and block;

select * from table where area is not null and area <> ''
                      and block is not null and block <> '';
```

I am getting different result sets on running these queries. What could possibly be the difference between them?

I thought the upper one returns where area and block both are present and the second one should return the same thing.

Comment: Thats two very different query

Comment: Have you got any link on what's generated by a where clause without comparison operator ? I can't get any result with a nullable varchar when trying on sqlFiddle : see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ba0c/1

Comment: Please look at it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76131/1/0

Comment: So it works on varchar if varchar contains an int?

Comment: Yes but why ? thats what i need to ask ? may be there are more cases

Comment: I asked the question there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885669/where-clause-without-operator

Comment: Thanks for asking there , i will keep on looking there...

Comment: @ralhp still one thing i want to ask, to get only those rows where both area and block contains values , second statement is valid or do i need to tweak it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of your second query is normal, though `is not null` is redundant because [any arithmetic comparison with `null` gives `null` as the result](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/working-with-null.html).

The quirk here is in the first query. MySQL is pretty generous (for better or for worse) with implicit type conversion. It treats a bare expression with no [comparison function or operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) as a valid predicate by implicitly converting the value of the evaluated expression to a boolean—which, in the world of MySQL, [is just an integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

Your `block` column is a `varchar`. MySQL's [documentation page on type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html) shows how values in this column will be implicitly converted to boolean (read: *integer*) values when supplied as a bare expression predicate:

> The following examples illustrate conversion of strings to numbers for
>   comparison operations:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
>         -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6';
>         -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
>         -> 1
> ```

What's implied here, but not stated outright, is that **if the string starts with a number, MySQL "guesses" that must be the number you wanted; otherwise, it 
"guesses" zero**. So if the value in `block` happens to be `'a'`, the first query is going to implicitly cast that to `0` and filter out the row because `WHERE area and 0` is never true. This is pretty unexpected if you're coming from a language that treats non-empty strings as true in a boolean context! But hey, it's MySQL... After a while, you learn to let go of expectations.

The second query doesn't do any implicit casting because [the `<>` operator is actually testing inequality](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal); `'a'` is clearly not equal to `''`, nor is it `null`, so both predicates are true and the row is not filtered from the result set.