# Where clause without operator

Tags: mysql

While trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885007/difference-in-resultsin-mysql-and-if-condition-for-nulls-applied#comment49810836_30885007), I found a syntax which I would have considered wrong

```
select * from table where area and block
```

I tried an sqlFiddle, and found it was valid.

But I've been unable to find how it works (all the doc I found was including operators)...

Made some try on an sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a7703/1)

It seems to "eliminate" null and 0 results for an nullable int field, or 0 result for a non nullable int field.

It also looks like it keeps varchar values... which contains int values (but not '0') !

Even if I don't think it's a good idea (at all) to use such syntax, I would appreciate if someone had any explanation on how this is managed...

Comment: This is obviously some MySQL built in coalescing shorthand. Changing your SqlFiddle to be SQL Server causes the queries to fail. I can't find any documentation on it either though.

Comment: @mattytommo Well, I'm sure this is not ANSI at all, indeed ;) But it looks quite different from a coalesce operator...

Comment: True, it's more like C#'s `IsNullOrEmpty` built into MySQL!

Comment: @mattytommo not really again, the strange part is the "field value, even varchar, must be an non zero int" part to return "true". So a `IsNullOrEmptyOrIsANonZeroInt` in c#. Which sadly doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation for Logical Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html):

> MySQL evaluates any nonzero, non-NULL value to TRUE. For example, the following statements all assess to TRUE:

```
mysql> SELECT 10 IS TRUE;<br/>
-> 1
mysql> SELECT -10 IS TRUE;<br/>
-> 1
mysql> SELECT 'string' IS NOT NULL;<br/>
-> 1
```

It seems that it evaluates any non-zero `int` field as `TRUE`.  Also, any `varchar` field which contains a number gets treated as numeric field.  I checked in your fiddle that a `varchar` field of `'0'` does **not** evaluate to `TRUE`.  And any `varchar` field which cannot be converted to a number does not evaluate to `TRUE` unless it is part of an `IS NOT NULL` expression.  Hence:

```
mysql> SELECT 'string' IS TRUE;<br/>
-> 0
```

From testing your fiddle, I found the following 2 queries to behave identically:

```
select * from test where ttt;
select * from test where ttt IS TRUE;
```

I don't have any definitive proof or source code, but it appears that MySQL actually *is* using an operator on the first query above even if it be omitted.

Comment: Thanks, seems the perfect way to investigate. Now, did you find anything where we can find an explanation on why a where clause without operator is somehow translated to a logical operator check ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: The expression is not really translated to a logical operator. Rather, think of it the other way around... when a comparison operation is evaulated, it returns a *value*, and that value is evaluated in a boolean context. An expression that doesn't contain a comparison operator also evaluates to a *value*. And that value is also evaluated in a boolean context. `NULL` evaluates to `NULL`, numeric value of 0 evaluates to boolean `FALSE`, and non-zero values evaluate to boolean `TRUE`. For character values evaluated in boolean context, those are evaluated in *numeric* context.

Comment: What's really going on is some *implicit* casting of datatypes. Consider the result from `SELECT '12cd34'+0`. The character string is implicitly cast to numeric. Other databases would throw an error, But MySQL is much more lenient. It converts the leading portion, whatever part it can, into a number, and discards the rest. If there aren't any leading characters that can be converted to a number, MySQL converts it to zero. The behavior you observe is a combination of a couple of things... how MySQL expressions evaluated in *boolean* context, and how MySQL implicitly converts datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

To add some clarification to the answer from Tim Biegeleisen...

In a `WHERE` clause, MySQL evaluates the expression as a *boolean* value. If the result of that expression is TRUE, the row is returned. Otherwise, the row is excluded.

The expression in the `WHERE` clause is *not* required to have a comparison operator. But it is convenient that the result from a comparison operator/operation (for example, **`foo = 'x'`**) is a *boolean* value.

In MySQL, a *boolean* TRUE value is represented as integer value `1`, FALSE is represented as integer value `0`, and NULL (of course) is `NULL`. And we can observe this behavior, e.g.

```
 SELECT TRUE + TRUE AS c1, FALSE AS c2
```

returns:

```
   c1    c2  
 ----  ----
    2     0
```

In MySQL, there are a lot of expressions that can be evaluated in *boolean* context. (I can't think of an expression offhand that cannot be, though MySQL does seem to get squirrelly with expressions that return DECIMAL values.)

Tim's answer suggests that MySQL is adding an `IS TRUE` comparison, and that these two statements are evaluated equivalently:

```
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE ttt;
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE ttt IS TRUE;
```

That's not too far off, because in a lot of cases, those queries do return the same result. But that's not really the best explanation, because those two statements are actually evaluated differently; these return *different* results in some corner cases.  As a demonstration, consider:

```
  CREATE TABLE test (ttt DECIMAL(18,9) PRIMARY KEY);
  INSERT INTO test (ttt) VALUES (0.48);
```

One the statements returns a row, the other doesn't. [SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63960/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63960/1)

---

It's really the `WHERE` clause that's requiring the expression to be evaluated as a boolean. That excludes rows where the expression does not evaluate to TRUE.

The `foo IS TRUE` is a test of the expression `foo` against a boolean value. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is

We'd expect these to be the same, but as demonstrated earlier, the `IS TRUE` test can give a different result than the evaluation of the expression in a `WHERE` clause.

---

In the `WHERE` clause, the expression is being evaluated as a boolean.

Evaluation integer values in boolean context is relatively easy... a NULL is (of course) NULL, an integer value of `0` is FALSE, and any other non-zero integer value is `TRUE`.

Evaluation of decimal/numeric values is a little more squirrelly, with values of foo, where `-0.5 > foo > 0.5`, in a boolean context, those values don't evaluate to TRUE. We workaround that squirrely-ness by building an expression to make the conversion explicit, instead defaulting to MySQL's implicit rounding behavior:

```
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE CEIL(ABS(ttt));
```

Even character strings can be evaluated in boolean context. MySQL implicitly casts the character string to a numeric. And then follows the same rules it does for numeric values.

A SQL expression that better matches the evaluation of `foo` in the WHERE clause is:

```
  ABS(SIGN(ROUND(t.foo+0,0))) AS `ASR foo+0`
```

(I'm not saying that this is actually the operation that MySQL is performing; I'm just saying this expression gets us a return that more closely matches the operation that MySQL performs.)

For various character values of foo:

```
  foo      foo+0  foo IS TRUE  ASR foo+0  WHERE foo
  ------  ------  -----------  ---------  ---------
  7x           7            1          1        yes
  -2.4      -2.4            1          1        yes
  0.0123  0.0123            1          0        no
  0            0            0          0        no
  (NULL)  (NULL)            0      (NULL)       no
```